# Changing the content in .txt file

Tags: power-automate

I have a manual daily task which I would like to automate. Below is the process separated in steps:

1. Text file is received via Email as attachment
2. Open the text file
3. Cut the 10 digit set of numbers on row 4
4. Paste the 10 digit set of numbers to row 16 after "|"
5. Save the file

This is the screenshot of the text file with the numbers which I cut and paste.

[image]

I have tried automating this by using Power Automate but don't have much of a progress.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to create a power automate flow without any success.

Comment: If would do that using [gawk](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm): ` awk 'NR==4{ a=$NF}NR==16{ $0=$0"|"a }1' inputfile > changedfile`

Comment: Desktop or cloud?  Also, if you've tried, then show us what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're focusing on the text manipulation - try this approach:
[image]

1. Action: example
2. Action: arrayLines - split the text by newline to get an array of each line
3. Action: result - bring them back together again... Expression of each tag:

Line 1: `join(take(outputs('arrayLines'), 3), decodeUriComponent('%0A'))`
Line 2: `first(split(outputs('arrayLines')[3], ' '))` 
Line 3: `join(take(skip(outputs('arrayLines'), 4), 12), decodeUriComponent('%0A'))` `last(split(outputs('arrayLines')[3], ' '))`
Line 4: `last(outputs('arrayLines'))`